# Search and replace multiple strings in multiple xml files via batch file

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, search, replace

I have some xml files (about 100, some in subfolders) whose IDs need to be changed. Therefore I have an Excel list with about 1.100 lines, left column is the old ID name and right column the new one which should replace the old one.

I found this script on Stackoverflow (and changed it a little):

```
@rem replaceids.bat

ECHO off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

SET source=%1
SET target=%2

IF EXIST %target% DEL /f %target%

FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('FINDSTR . %source%') DO (
   SET line=%%i
   SET line=!line:ö=oe!
   SET line=!line:ä=ae!
   SET line=!line:ü=ue!
   ECHO !line! >> %target%
)
```

Here's the original link:
[batch replace multiple different strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744230/batch-replace-multiple-different-strings)

Then I created another batch file to call the one above and run it through my files:

```
for /R %%F in (*.xml) do (
   replaceids.bat "%%~dpnxF" "C:\mytargetfolder%%~pnxF"
)
```

Found this on Stackoverflow as well; here's the link:
[Batch process all files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642021/batch-process-all-files-in-directory)

Also thanks to Meltz014 from reddit, who helped me get this far.

The problem I have now is that it says that the network path can not be found when I start it (not sure what it says exactly in English since I'm not in the office and running it on a German Windows right now). As far as I can see I'm not referencing to any networks.

Any help would be appreciated.

My command line experience is very limited by the way.

EDIT

I just found something else that might get me closer, it still doesn't work yet though:
[How to Find Replace Multiple strings in multiple text files using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164000/how-to-find-replace-multiple-strings-in-multiple-text-files-using-powershell)

```
$Iteration = 0
$FDPATH = 'D:\opt\HMI\Gfilefind_rep'
#& 'D:\usr\fox\wp\bin\tools\fdf_g.exe' $FDPATH\*.fdf
$GraphicsList = Get-ChildItem -Path $FDPATH\*.g | ForEach-Object FullName
$FindReplaceList = Import-Csv -Path $FDPATH\Input.csv
foreach($Graphic in $Graphicslist){
    Write-Host "Processing Find Replace on : $Graphic"
    foreach($item in $FindReplaceList){
    Get-Content $Graphic | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "$($item.FindString)", "$($item.ReplaceString)" } | Set-Content ($Graphic+".tmp")
        Remove-Item $Graphic
        Rename-Item ($Graphic+".tmp") $Graphic
        $Iteration = $Iteration +1
        Write-Host "String Replace Completed for $($item.ReplaceString)"
    }
}
```

It seems to do something, but then after finnishing it always says

> String Replace Completed for

My CSV file is created as it is in the example, that means:

```
FindString  ReplaceString
AA1A    171PIT9931A
BB1B    171PIT9931B
etc..
```

Since it doesn't find anything, I assume something with the CSV might be wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You'll  need a different approach tto deal with all the `<>`usually be present in xml files. All your unquoted handling of the line content will get interpreted as input/outputredirection. You should also check what encoding the xml files have - UTF8/UTF16 will be problematic with pure batch.

Comment: It's UTF-8. What approach would you recommend? @LotPings

Answer (score 0):

Probably 1 command line to help your work: (`%a` = old-id, `%b` = new-id)

`for /f "tokens=1,2" %a in (ids-list.csv) do msr -rp dir1,dirN -f "\.xml$" -x "%a" -o "%b" -R`

- Remove `-R` if want to preview result before changing the file;
- Replace the `%a` to `%%a` and `%b` to `%%b` if you put above command in a file.

Don't quite catch your question. I think it's better to tell 2 points:

- What's your inputs ?
- What's your required output ?

Assume:

- You've a source old/new id list file: `ids-list.csv`
- You want to recursively search and replace in folders: `dir1,dir2-N`

`msr.exe` is a single portable exe tool in `tools` in my open project https://github.com/qualiu/msr. You can use Regex replace (`-t`) instead of plain-text(`-x`), and ignore-case (`-i`). More info: https://qualiu.github.io/msr/usage-by-running/msr-Windows.html

Additinally:

- If your `ids-list.csv` is separated by `,` instead of white-space, use:

  `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %a in (ids-list.csv)`
- If your `ids-list.csv` is more complicated, like:

  `"old-id-1","new-id-1"
  "old-id-2","new-id-2"`

  `for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('msr -p ids-list.csv -t ".*\W(.+?)\W,\W(.+?)\W.*" -o "$1 $2" -PAC')`